# Oracle Apex 5.1 Multiple Tabular Forms on a single page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, tabular, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently struggling to show multiple tabular forms on one page. Oracle Apex allows only one Tabular Form on a page. I tried to follow the guide from the "Planet of Apex" blog but unfortunately it didn't work.

I didn't manage to implent the iFrame Regions to set the values of the foreign keys.

[image: I only want to see the highlighted table]

```
 <iframe src="f?p=&APP_ID.:23:&SESSION."style="width:600px;height:600px"scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"  />
```

And how do I bind the variables in the URL, like this `&ITEM/COLUMN.`?

The guide I followed:
https://planetoftheapex.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/multiple-tabular-forms-on-a-single-page-workaround/

Comment: Please include your code you are working on in minimal, complete and verifiable version. It will be easier for other users to help you...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Interactive Grid?  You can have several Interactive Grids on a single Apex page.  Check out sample packaged application [Interactive Grid](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=158456:LOGIN::::::)  -- User name `DEMO` and password `demo` -- and play around with all the features.  Very powerful.

When in Application Express, you can edit an existing page, and add a "Interactive Grid" region, specify the SQL query to populate the grid.  Then add another "Interactive Grid" region, etc.  Or using the Create Page wizard, choose "Report" as a page type, and on the next page, choose Interactive Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use Interactive Grid but unfortunately, it didn't work well. Each instance of an IG on your page will slow your page load in about 2 seconds. In my case, I had to have 5 tabular forms (or IG) on the same page and the result was unacceptable 10 seconds.

I even did a quick demo on apex.oracle.com with 5 IG's based on emp/dept tables and the result was the same: each IG slowed the page in about 2 secs.

My guess is that if I had thousands of rows to load, the IG would still take 2 seconds, so if you have tons of rows it'd be fine. But for few rows, it doesn't work well.

Answering the original question: I've created an application item to store the Foreign Key so I don't need to pass it in my URL. That may help you.